# Can I call a shell script from CodeIgniter which will in turn call a codeigniter controller function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, shell

I am somewhat of a newbie.
I am writing a social app in Codeigniter. Once the user logs in, many things have to be done to prepare the user network, send email, create a list of recommended friends, etc.
We have already written functions to do that each of these.

Lets say there is the main Controller index with function SignUp.

After Sign up, we want to redirect the user to Dashboard controller but in the background, we want to run

1. BuildNetwork
2. FindMatches
3. Send Emails

I dont know how to run any task in background. So I was thinking maybe I can write a shell script that calls these functions one after the other.
We will call this script through Codeigniter and pass the UserId.
Then this script will call individual functions and pass the userId to those.

Can anyone tell me

1. If this is the right approach
2. How is it done (this way or in any other way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you use a queue system instead, checkout something like beanstalk (and the PHP library pheanstalk).

You would then put a job in the queue for each thing you want doing, and then in your background process (cron maybe), you would fetch jobs and run them.

http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/
https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk/

So, in your SignUp function, you would create a job and put in the queue, you could use a queue for each different type of job, then have a job consumer for each queue.

```
// some pseudo code

function signUp()
{
    $jobData = json_encode(array(
        'template' => 'newUser',
        'to'       => 'john@example.com'
    ));
    $this->pheanstalk->useTube('OutboundEmails')->put($jobData);

    // add other jobs for other tasks here too
}
```

Then you could have cron script that runs your consumer scripts.

```
// pseudo for this mail consumer

$pheanstalk->watch('OutboundEmails')->ignore('default');

while ($job = $pheanstalk->reserve())
{
    // send the email using the data in the job
    $job->getData() // returns your JSON
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That sounds like a good way to do it. Let me try that. Doesnt cron job run at specific times? Or we will have to check this queue every few seconds? I would ideally prefer a push system where the process runs only if its needed.

Comment: You can schedule cron to run when you want, but as the reserve command blocks when no jobs are available you are effectively doing that. I've used this approach in a high load, high job environment, and have found beanstalk and pheanstalk to be excellent for this sort of thing.

Comment: im trying to install beanstalk on ubuntu. 
Tried 
sudo apt-get install beanstalkd
Then ./beanstalkd -l 198.211.120.233 -p 11300
But I get the error -bash: ./beanstalkd: No such file or directory
I know this is not a server forum.. but I just posted to say that I am working on trying the suggested solution and will report once I am able to test it =)

Comment: Well the approach is sound, and used in many places. But yes I would ask on serverfault. Accept answer or upvote at least?

Comment: Hi,  I finally implemented Pheanstalk (sorry there were some other bugs to fix that took a while ) - this works great. I am currently testing by running the consumer script in another browser - but will figure out how to keep this alive. Thanks for all your help

Comment: No problem, glad it's working well for you. Your consumer (that fetches jobs and processes them) can be run in the background via cron , rather than on page request.

Comment: We used Supervisord (http://supervisord.org/) to keep beanstalk and listener script running. Works great. :) Will write a detailed step by step instruction here or on a blog when I have some time. Thanks @Catchamonkey for all your help.